# Как получить количество знаков после точки?

Tags: php

Получаю `4` а должен быть ответ `5` так как `0.00001 * 5 = 0.00005` после точки это `5` знаков

Почему выводит 4?

```
 $price = '0.000010';
 $details = 5;

$fix = strlen(explode('.', (string) ((float) rtrim($price, '0') * $details))[1]); // 4
```

Comment: А вы разбейте всю эту монструозную строку на маленькие отдельные операции и посмотрите что в каком месте идёт не так....

Comment: @Алексей это просто обрезается в конце 0 => '0.00001'

Comment: Никакой ошибки в коде не вижу, по идее должен правильно работать, непойму откуда 4 взялась

Comment: Ещё раз..... разбейте всю эту монструозную строку на маленькие отдельные операции и посмотрите что в каком месте идёт не так..... можно после каждой строчки **отдельной операции** делать echo. всё будет прекрасно видно

Comment: Алексей, понял)) сижу думаю а у меня там в строке `5.0e-5` )) а как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Ну если чуть-чуть погрязнить, то можно number_format  использовать. Чтобы вначале задать числу формат, умножить на что надо и потом только отпилить нули... типа такого `$test = rtrim(number_format($price * $details, 7), 0);
$fix = strlen(explode('.', $test)[1]);
echo $fix;`   где вместо числа 7  может быть задано приемлемое число, за которое точно не будет выходить мантисса